# What is meaning of "hrtimer" in the output of `ps -elf`?

Tags: ps, scheduling

As the subject, here is the related output:

```
F S UID         PID   PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  STIME TTY          TIME CMD

0 S john     124024 118530  0  80   0 -  4930 hrtime 05:09 pts/9    00:00:00 TimerExample

1 I root     125459      2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 05:12 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u256:2]

0 S john     126099  59086  0  80   0 -  3589 hrtime 05:14 ?        00:00:00 sleep 1
```

There is no relation information in linux program manual (`man ps, man proc`). I would be grateful to have some with this question.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the waiting function in the kernel. There is no list, you have to go through the kernel sources. Also `ps -ax -o pid,cmd,wchan=WIDE-WCHAN-COLUMN` makes it a bit more readable.

Comment: What do you mean by "There is no list."? Could explain that in simpler words?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one clue:

> For standard resolution (at jiffy resolution), a clock will have a
>   value for it's '.resolution' field equal to the period of a jiffy. For
>   embedded machines, where HZ is typically 100, this will be 10
>   milliseconds, or 10000000 (ten million) nanoseconds.
>
> Also for standard resolution, the Clock Event Device will have an
>   event handler of "tick_handle_periodic".
>
> For high resolution, the resolution of the clock will be listed as 1
>   nanosecond (which is ridiculous, but serves as an indicator of
>   essentially arbitrary precision.) Also, the Clock Event Device will
>   have an event handler of "hrtimer_interrupt".